# Django skip inline field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an inline where the first field is always selected by default. Since both are required, is it possible to only validate and insert/update when the second field is also selected or I need to also define a default value for the second field? (Otherwise I will always get errors on the rows where only the first field is set...)

**Update**

I'm overriding the first widget (TextInput) render. If I set to empty then it works but I want this field to behave almost like a label.

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if name == "opinion_set-0-topic":
            value = "first thing"
        if name == "opinion_set-1-topic":
            value = "second thing"
        if name == "opinion_set-2-topic":
            value = "third thing"
```

**Update 2**

I need something like, if field 2 isn't set (gives "This field is required.") then bypass the form error and simply ignore the rows where this happens...

Comment: Can you post some of your code? If the value of the first field is the same as it's initial/default value and no other fields have been changed, then Django should treat the form as not changed, and  not validate the inline.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is:

- you have a main form to save

  you have an inline subform with mandatory fields, some with default values and some without default values

Then, if you don't set all mandatory values in the inline, you get "This field is required" error.

One way to skip this situation is defining "extra = 0" in the admin.py definition of the inline form.

This way you are not forced to insert an inline object along the main one, but you can do it if you want, just clicking "`+ Add another &lt;inline&gt;`".